# Why 's my HP Laptop's HDMI turning off when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: laptop, power-management, hp, hdmi

**HP PAVILION G6

UBUNTU 12.10**

I've disabled the screen-saver, suspend etc from `gconf-editor` and `/etc/.../` sys files only to fail in my quest each time with no particular success.
 This might've been a hardware problem but then again, windows didn't had this problem at all, giving me hope... somewhere... buried deep in those sys files! There is no *suspend* or *sleep* involved, all that happens is a *screen-off* more like a power cut-off to the HDMI port and laptop screen together.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it the average user way:

1. in the settings window (gnome-control-center), choose the "power" management settings
2. in the on "When the lid is closed" section, choose "Do nothing"

Works fine here, on a Thinkpad T430S.